# In SQL Server Management Studio, how do I ignore the first column in a table when bulk inserting from a csv fle?

Tags: sql, csv, insert, bulk

Keep in mind that I am student, so I can not modify the csv file. It must also be coded and no "special tools" are allowed. I have these statements in SQL:

Schema and table creation:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IA;
GO

CREATE TABLE IA.CONTACTS
(
    CONT_GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CONT_FNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONT_LNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONT_DOB DATE,
    CONT_CALLS INTEGER
);
```

Attempt to bulk insert from a csv file:

```
BULK INSERT IA.IA.Contacts   
FROM 'C:\Users\k20\Desktop/IA.CONTACTS.csv'  
WITH   
   (FIRSTROW = 2,
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

I get this error:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 2, column 1 (CONT_GUID).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 3, column 1 (CONT_GUID).
>
> .... and so on, for every row in the csv file

I have 4 columns in my csv file, but 5 in my table. How do I ignore the first one from the table, `CONT_GUID`?

EDIT:

```
CONT_FNAME  CONT_LNAME  CONT_DOB    CONT_CALLS
Mary    May 1/25/1980   2
John    James   1/13/1978   3
Martin  Merriweather    4/25/1988   1
James   Johns   6/13/1990   1
Jerry   Jacobs  11/11/1996  1
Madelyn Mace    3/30/1995   2
Bruce   Blake   1/30/1970   4
Brian   Brown   12/4/1980   2
Charlie Childress   2/13/1987   3
Ray Rhodes  12/23/1989  1
William Willis  11/13/1985  1
Herman  Hughes  3/1/1980    2
Steve   Stevens 5/12/1984   2
Daryl   Dixon   9/25/1983   3
Abe Avery   8/24/1987   5
Kevin   Carlyle 10/15/1975  3
Sean    Shaffer 10/25/1977  3
Peter   Piper   8/6/1974    3
Oscar   Oosker  7/2/1973    2
Tom Townsend    6/6/1965    1
Victor  Vaughn  6/13/1966   1
Nick    Nice    7/12/1968   1
Sally   Soose   6/12/1984   1
June    Johnson 12/16/1984  1
```

It's directly from the csv file. Commas with no spaces are used as the separators.

Comment: Could you also add some sample rows from your csv file?

Comment: if the file is not that big, load them into a staging table which has 4 columns, and then create an sql to move them into the final table specifying the 4 columns to insert to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load them into a staging table which has 4 columns, and then create an sql to insert them into the final table specifying the 4 columns to insert to.

I don't know about the unique identify syntax you have above, but you have specified newid() works, so the following should be the complete answer

```
CREATE TABLE IA.CONTACTS
(
CONT_GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NOT NULL,
CONT_FNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONT_LNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONT_DOB DATE,
CONT_CALLS INTEGER
)

BULK INSERT 
IA.IA.Staging_Contacts  
   FROM 'C:\Users\k20\Desktop/IA.CONTACTS.csv'  
   WITH   
      (  
        FIRSTROW=2,
        KEEPIDENTITY,
         FIELDTERMINATOR =',',  
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'  
      );

insert into contacts (CONT_GUID,CONT_FNAME ,CONT_LNAME,CONT_DOB,CONT_CALLS )
select newid(),CONT_FNAME ,CONT_LNAME,CONT_DOB,CONT_CALLS 
from staging_contacts
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this and it got rid of the long error. But now I get this:
"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CONT_GUID', table 'IA.IA.CONTACTS'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."
 
The CONT_GUID has to be a unique identifier, how can automatically set a new id per record?

Comment: I fixed it. I just used NewID() when selecting from the staging table.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore a field in Bulk Insert, recommended to load all the fields and drop or delete the values in the column you don't want OR load all the fields into a staging table, make changes in the staging table and load it into final table(Target)